# Spark UDF error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I found similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63595546/f-regexp-extract-in-a-udf-returns-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attri) , but no answer provided how to fix the issue.

I want to make a UDF, that would extract for me words from column. So, I want to create a column named `new_column`, by applying my UDF to `old_column`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_extract

re_string = 'some|words|I|need|to|match'

def regex_extraction(x,re_string):
    return regexp_extract(x,re_string,0)

extracting = udf(lambda row: regex_extraction(row,re_string))

df = df.withColumn("new_column", extracting(col('old_column')))
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

How to fix my function? I have many columns and want to loop through columns list and apply my UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a UDF. UDF is required when you cannot do something using PySpark, so you need some python functions or libraries. In your case your can have a function which accepts a column and returns a column, but that's it, UDF is not needed.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract
df = spark.createDataFrame([('some match',)], ['old_column'])

re_string = 'some|words|I|need|to|match'

def regex_extraction(x, re_string):
    return regexp_extract(x, re_string, 0)

df = df.withColumn("new_column", regex_extraction('old_column', re_string))
df.show()
# +----------+----------+
# |old_column|new_column|
# +----------+----------+
# |some match|      some|
# +----------+----------+
```

"Looping" through columns in a list can be implemented this way:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df = spark.createDataFrame([('some match', 'match')], cols)

re_string = 'some|words|I|need|to|match'
def regex_extraction(x, re_string):
    return regexp_extract(x, re_string, 0)

df = df.select(
    '*',
    *[regex_extraction(c, re_string).alias(f'new_{c}') for c in cols]
)
df.show()
# +----------+-----+--------+--------+
# |      col1| col2|new_col1|new_col2|
# +----------+-----+--------+--------+
# |some match|match|    some|   match|
# +----------+-----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: thank you very much! What means `'*',` ? And another question I want to loop through the list of columns and apply not one but two functions? how to do that? For example I have a func that looks smth like this `def mapping_func(x,deviceDict): try: return deviceDict.get(x,x) except: return None map_func = udf(lambda row : mapping_func(row,deviceDict)) df = df.withColumn("device_type", map_func(col("device_type"))`. Link to question with this func: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976237/pyspark-replacing-value-in-a-column-by-searching-a-dictionary

Comment: @good_day - `'*'` selects all the existing columns in the df. And for the other question, I think you should create a separate question.